# Issues updating existing field and add new fields at the same time

Tags: json, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to update the `"Current bid price"` value with the value from the `bid amount` of the `bidder` while adding a bidder array to the JSON. The idea is to update the
`"Current bid price"`with the bid amount whenever a bidder is added.

my json object does not have a bidder array, but when it is updated with the bidder, the current bid price should be updated with bid amount

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62266e4feb82220b6ccbe5a3"),
        "user" : 10,
        "name" : "Panamera",
        "category" : "Porche",
        "description" : "Exclusively Fast",
        "closing date" : "12/10/22",
        "starting bid price" : "1250.00",
        "Current bid price" : "0.00",
        "auction status" : "open"
}
```

bidder

```
bidder: [
      {
       "user": "Bob Marley",
       "date and time": ISODate("2022-03-11T00:00:00Z"),
       "bid amount": "450.00",
      }
      ]
```

when I try to run an update code it only updates the current bid price and it doesn't add the bidder array to the json

```
db.auction.update({"name": "Panamera"},
                  {$set: {"Current bid price": "450.00"}},
                  {$push: {"bidder":{ "user": "Bob Marley","date and time": ISODate("2022-03-11T00:00:00Z"),"bid amount": "450.00"}}})
```

using the set and push function with the above code, this is what I am trying to achieve but I cannot make it happen with a single code

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62266e4feb82220b6ccbe5a3"),
        "user" : 10,
        "name" : "Panamera",
        "category" : "Porche",
        "description" : "Exclusively Fast",
        "closing date" : "12/10/22",
        "starting bid price" : "1250.00",
        "Current bid price" : "450.00",
        "auction status" : "open",
        "bidder" : [
                {
                        "user" : "Bob Marley",
                        "date and time" : ISODate("2022-03-11T00:00:00Z"),
                        "bid amount" : "450.00"
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the issue, I needed to wrap the push with the set. thanks

```
db.auction.update({"name": "Panamera"},
                {$push: {"bidder":{ "user": "Bob Marley","date and time": 
                ISODate("2022-03-11T00:00:00Z"),"bid amount": "450.00"}},
                $set: {"Current bid price": "450.00"}})
```